# Ruby On Rails Tutorial 10.3.1 User Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The sample test has names that will not pass validation.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'index'" do


    describe "for signed-in users" do

      before(:each) do
        @user = test_sign_in(Factory(:user))
        second = Factory(:user, :name => "Bob", :email => "another@example.com")
        third  = Factory(:user, :name => "Ben", :email => "another@example.net")

        @users = [@user, second, third]
      end

      it "should be successful" do
        get :index
        response.should be_success
      end

      it "should have the right title" do
        get :index
        response.should have_selector("title", :content => "All users")
      end

      it "should have an element for each user" do
        get :index
        @users.each do |user|
          response.should have_selector("li", :content => user.name)
        end
      end
    end
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

The name has to be six characters long.  Bob and Ben will not pass.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :name, :email,:password,:password_confirmation

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name, :presence => true,
  :length   =>{ :within => 6..40}
```

The solution (albeit trivial) was to change the names to Bobbob and Benben.

I hope that is helpful for someone.

Best,

Evan